# How to access slim app requests on a shorten url

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim, apache2.4, url-shortener

I have a simple SLIM application that responds to all requests to sent it in an API-like way for example the following url:

```
http://example.com/pages/subdirectory/slimApp.php/products
```

As you can see, the url to the slim app is absolute and pretty long but I have tried using Apache2 mod_rewrite to shorten the url as shown below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /pages/
RewriteRule ^slimApp/(.*) subdirectory/slimApp.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

The code above rewrites to the main route of the app which is basically a 404 error page and acts like no request has been specified. When I access the app with an absolute url, it works as normal but if I try to access /products from the shorten url version, it fails with a slim 404 page.

Basically what I need is to translate the following and still be able to handle requests like `shortened_url/products`, `shortened_url/something_else`, etc. For-example:

```
http://example.com/pages/subdirectory/slimApp.php/products
```

to

```
http://example.com/slimApp/products
```

Bear in mind that /products is dynamic, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file located?

Comment: @MrWhite The file is at the root directory.  http://example.com/.htaccess

Comment: The directive you posted should already do as you require. What other directives do you have? What other `.htaccess` files? I'm assuming `slimApp.php` is your slim front-controller and not a _directory_?

Comment: Yes slimApp.php is the front-controller. Everything works wit the full/absolute url and fails wit the short url. Resolves to slim 404 error meaning that atleast slim is receiving the request but doesn't acknowledge it.

Comment: This url works fine |> http://example.com/pages/subdirectory/slimApp.php/products
But http://example.com/slimApp/products gives a slim 404 error and it seems like apache2 is still checking the shortened url when it shouldn't cuz if it does, then slim work be able to address the requests in that url context